# How to calculate TAS and fuel for Diamond DA20-C1?

Tags: performance-calculation, density-altitude

The PoH for the Diamond DA20-C1 is here: http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/Canada/Tech_Pubs_DA20-C1/AFM/DA202-C1-Rev-28.pdf.

The plane has an MT prop, and the supplement for it is here: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59b981e8b07869d96fe0c365/t/5e457224a5db6b6a6ce00bc2/1581609513640/DA20+MT+Propeller+Supplement+%283%29.pdf.

I need to calculate fuel consumption and TAS under the following conditions:

- 8000' pressure altitude (PA)
- 2600 RPM
- -1C OAT

There's two charts in the supplement that I think I need to solve this:
[image]
[image]

It seems I need to use the first graph to find the density altitude (DA) from the temperature and PA. So for -1C and 8000, the DA appears to be 8000 as well. Looking at the table, this would give me 7.1 GPH and 132 TAS. Is this correct? I'm confused by the "standard temperature" heading in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, I don't see how I can use it to solve my problem. If you know what to do, would you mind explaining your ideas in an answer? I think I'm suppose to stick with the PoH and prop supplement to solve this.

Comment: The standard temperature line represents air in standard conditions forgiven density altitude, which is also equal to the pressure altitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are all correct, as is your answer.

> I'm confused by the "standard temperature" heading in the table.

Consider this table from your first link:

> [image]

The column I put in a green box, if it was the only one, then the altitudes would all be density altitudes -- just like the table in the question, with the label "Standard Temperature."